# glab Changelog generating changelog sorted by tagged versions

Tags: git, gitlab, changelog

I am using Gitlab Changelog API to generate the changelog. For example, if I run:

`glab changelog generate --from 66d2f48e348bb9fc65a92647cb24f1f301fcbb4c`

It will generate the changelog for me:

```
## 3.4.0
 (2023-12-19)

### added (5 changes)

 - [modified ci script to add job id](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@de2babcc4c101504364949f72a38c355a6db2e18)
 - [adding trailer via cmd line](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@5263ee4c0520fc050ef8bb4831a79652f3b8f3cf)
 - [random shit feature completed](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@89164b648f1c6323fe6c456371d2aa9ed2bc843d)
 - [temperature measurements supports new sensor](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@3e2c90e7f565f155f3af832974ad3ac0ab5bb134)
 - [new feature for 2.9.0](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@905551aaea9a18b9cb00a2db00abf85e271a7bb0)
```

The one thing I do not like is that the changes are not ordered by their tagged versions. See my repository:

[image]

As you can see from above, I have a bunch of changes  tagged with different versions. When I am generating a changelog, I would like to know what changes were made on specific tagged versions. For example. I would expect something like that:

```
# 3.4.0
### added (1 changes)
 - [modified ci script to add job id](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@de2babcc4c101504364949f72a38c355a6db2e18)

# 3.2.0
### added (1 changes)
- [adding trailer via cmd line](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@5263ee4c0520fc050ef8bb4831a79652f3b8f3cf)

# 3.1.0
### added (1 changes)
- [random shit feature completed](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@89164b648f1c6323fe6c456371d2aa9ed2bc843d)

# 3.0.0
### added (1 changes)
- [temperature measurements supports new sensor](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@3e2c90e7f565f155f3af832974ad3ac0ab5bb134)

# 2.9.0
### added (1 changes)
- [new feature for 2.9.0](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@905551aaea9a18b9cb00a2db00abf85e271a7bb0)
```

Could someone help me understand how can this be achieved? Perhaps I should use a custom `.gitlab/changelog_config.yml` template to achieve this? Appreciate in advance!